# HTML Drop down menu with text input also

Tags: php, html

I want to create a drop down html button with numbers 1 through 100. That also allows for text input. I want it too look something like this:

[image: drop down button]

I know that html has a select input type where I can specify what I want in the dropdown menu, but it does not have the text input option that I also want. How would I go about this using html and php?

Answer (score -1):

See this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp
Is that a datalist what are you looking for?

```html
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```